# Error in library("ggpmisc") : there is no package called ‘ggpmisc’

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have `ggplot2` installed and `library(ggplot2)` runs. However, I get the following error when I try to run `library(ggpmisc)`. I have tried restarting R and reinstalling `ggplot2` to no avail. In addition, I can generate plots using `ggplot2` but can't access functions like `stat_poly_eq` since I can't open `ggpmisc`. I have the current version of RStudio installed

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpmisc)
```

> Error in library(ggpmisc) : there is no package called ‘ggpmisc’

Comment: Because `ggpmisc` is not install along with `ggplot2`. you need to install `ggpmisc`: `install.packages("ggpmisc")` (see: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ggpmisc/versions/0.3.3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you installed the library `ggpmisc`? If you haven't please run:

```
install.packages("ggpmisc")
```

and then run

```
library("ggpmisc")
```

and now everything should work!

As it is in it's [CRAN webpage](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggpmisc/index.html), ggpmisc is a set of "Extensions to 'ggplot2' respecting the grammar of graphics paradigm." i.e. isn't a part of ggplot. That means that the packages are not binded, so each one should be installed individually.

Answer (score 0):

I found one solution reinstalling R only with 64 bits version, previoulsy I have installed 32 and 64 b version. That works for me.

Comment: From your answer I infer that you have run into the same error message but in your case, the accepted answer did not help. In your case it turned out that you had two R versions installed at the same time which caused the problem?

I'd suggest stating that explicitly as without context your answer appears a bit weird compared to the accepted one.